# cannot get length of array passed as a function parameter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would get a length of an array that I pass in the parameter of a function

I have an array of object

```
groupList:group[]=[];
```

in `selectItem` I call `testExistinginArray` function

```
selectItem (event) {
    if(!this.toggle) {
        this.groupList.push(event);
    }
    else{
        this.ejList.push(event);
        if(!this.testExistinginArray(event,this.groupList)) { //I pass groupList as parameter
            this.groupList.push({code:event.codeBusinessGroup,name:event.nameBusinessGroup})
        }
    }
}

testExistinginArray(event,type: any[]) {
    for(let i=0;i<this.type.length;i++) {
        if (this.type[i].code.indexOf(event.codeBusinessGroup)===-1) {
            return false
        }
        else{
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Actually I get undefined length error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Comment: How is `selectItem` called ?

Comment: in html input ` (onSelect)="selectItem($event)"` of [this component](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/autocomplete)
`

Comment: Use `type.length` instead of `this.type.length`. Here `type` is not function variable, it's argument variable. So you can't read using `this`

Comment: yes I have forgotten to delete `this` after changing var. you can put it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @infodev Added as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `type.length` instead of `this.type.length`. Here `type` is not function variable, it's argument variable. So you can't read using `this`

Answer (score 0):

You tried to extract attribute `length` from `this.type`, not from function parameter `type`. Looks like typo